# matching vector families that form a group

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory, algebra, group-theory, finite-sets

Is there any research/information on matching vector family sets (the U list or the V list or both) that form a group (under addition)?

You can find the definition of MV families here:
[https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~anuprao/pubs/codingtheory/lecture11.pdf](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Eanuprao/pubs/codingtheory/lecture11.pdf)